# Add Custom checkout field to Order in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, woocommerce-subscriptions

The WooCommerce 3.0 update has not been kind to me. I have added a custom required field to checkout for a domain name, and am having trouble figuring out how to get it to save now. This code adds the field properly still:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'add_domain_checkout_field' );

function add_domain_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

    echo '<div id="add_domain_checkout_field"><h2>' . __('Domain') . '</h2>';

    woocommerce_form_field( 'sitelink_domain', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'required' => true,
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('Domain where SiteLink will be installed'),
        'placeholder'   => __('Enter your URL'),
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'sitelink_domain' ));

    echo '</div>';

}
```

And I am trying to save it, this way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'add_domain_to_order_meta', 10, 2 );
function add_domain_to_order_meta( $order, $data ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['sitelink_domain'] ) ) {
        $order->add_meta_data( 'ssla_sitelink_url', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['sitelink_domain'] ) );
    }
}
```

However the meta does not appear to be added or saved anywhere.

I know that the **`$_POST`** variable is there, I have error logged it out to see.

Testing some grabbing and error logging confuses me further:

```
$sitelink_domain        = $subscription->get_meta_data( 'ssla_sitelink_url' );
error_log( print_r(  $sitelink_domain, true ) );
```

// Output is:

```
[21-Apr-2017 01:26:27 UTC] Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 270086
            [key] => _ssla_sitelink_url
            [value] => lololol.com
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 270089
            [key] => _download_permissions_granted
            [value] => 1
        )

)
```

However,

```
$sitelink_domain        = $subscription->get_meta( 'ssla_sitelink_url' );
error_log( 'Domain: ' . $sitelink_domain );
```

Output is just:

```
[21-Apr-2017 01:27:39 UTC] Domain:
```

Comment: How are you initializing `$subscription` ? Remember that the subscription order and the order are not the same even though they share a lot of data.

Comment: Subscription is coming passed in through the hook I am using, `woocommerce_subscription_status_updated` and it looks like for some reason `add_meta_data()` is prefixing the key with an underscore? I tried `$subscription->get_meta( '_ssla_sitelink_url' );` and it pulls it properly...

Answer (score 6):

First you need to validate the field when the checkout form is posted and the field is required and not optional using **`woocommerce_checkout_process`** action hook:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'domain_checkout_field_process');
function domain_checkout_field_process() {
    // Check if it's set and if it's not set, we add an error.
    if ( ! $_POST['sitelink_domain'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please enter the domain where the SiteLink will be installed.' ), 'error' );
}
```

As this is a checkout custom field, you can use **`woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta`** action hook to save the new field to order custom fields:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'domain_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );

function domain_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['sitelink_domain'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'ssla_sitelink_url', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['sitelink_domain'] ) );
    }
}
```

Use **`woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address`** action hook to display the custom field value on the admin order edition page:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'domain_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );
function domain_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
    // Get the custom field value
    $domain_siteLink = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'ssla_sitelink_url', true );
    // Display the custom field:
    echo '<p><strong>' . __('Domain SiteLink', 'woocommerce') . ': </strong>' . $domain_siteLink . '</p>';
}
```

Display the custom field label and value in frontend orders and email notifications:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'custom_custom', 10, 3 );
function custom_custom( $item_id, $item, $order ){
    // Get the custom field value
    $domain_siteLink = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'ssla_sitelink_url', true );
    // Display the custom field:
    echo '<p><strong>' . __('Domain SiteLink', 'woocommerce') . ': </strong>' . $domain_siteLink . '</p>';
}
```

This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

This code works for WooCommerce 3.0+

Comment: Hello @LoicTheAztec Sir Is there any way to prevent saving new order for specific customer-id, I have a list of blacklisted customer-id  and I want to show a custom error when admin select blacklisted customer and click on save order then show error msg instead of placing an order  but woocommerce_checkout_process and other hook's I have tried are not working

Comment: @KamaleshM.Talaviya Yes this is possible… Ask a new question for that providing the code you tried with explanations, then notify me here.

Comment: Hello @LoicTheAztec Sir I have created a new question with details all I need to know is the backend hook name where I can check conditions and return error msg , it will be great if you can help me with that thank you.
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64525494/woocommerce-how-to-prevent-saving-new-order-from-backend-and-frontend-as-well-fo

Answer (score 0):

You may add additional order meta data like below.

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_order_item_meta','add_values_to_order_item_meta',1,2);
if(!function_exists('add_values_to_order_item_meta'))
{
  function add_values_to_order_item_meta($item_id, $values)
  {
        global $woocommerce,$wpdb;
        $user_custom_values = $values['user_custom_data_value'];
        if(!empty($user_custom_values))
        {
            wc_add_order_item_meta($item_id,'user_custom_data',$user_custom_values);  
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear if the OP needs order item meta or regular order meta, but this approach will add the `user_custom_data_value` to every product being ordered. Additionally, you can clean up your code by removing the globals that you aren't using and removing the `function_exists` check since there's no need to check if it exists when you are defining it yourself.